# Polymer app-route: multiple routes to same page?

Tags: routes, polymer

Is there a built-in method for routing multiple possible links to the same "page"?

For example, I have a '/' route that loads a landing page by binding the active attribute of that route to a property named landing-active, which is being observed. The most straightforwards way I can think of to allow converging routes is to create another app-route element for the new route, and bind its active attribute to the same landing-active property as the '/' route.

Is there a better/different way of handling this, or should I stick with my method?

**Edit**: I tried my method out, and it doesn't work. Here's my original route:

```
<app-route
  id='landing-route'
  route='{{route}}'
  pattern='/'
  active='{{landing-active}}'>
</app-route>
```

If I then add an alternate route by simply changing the pattern and id, then the '/' route no longer works. Changing the active binding on the new route fixes this issue, but also no longer allows it to rout as intended. So my conclusion is that I can't bind the same property to the active attribute of two separate app-route elements, so my routing method doesn't work.

What alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 1):

- **Option 1:** Use two separate `active` variables for your two `<app-route>`s, and test for either variable (e.g., with a computed [binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/data-binding#annotated-computed)/[property](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/observers#define-a-computed-property)).
- **Option 2:** Use a different router component. [`<nebula-routing>`](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/arsnebula/nebula-routing) might be the best option IMO, given that it has a similar API to `<app-route>` and supports regular expression in the route patterns.

Comment: Option 1 is so obvious, I'm an idiot. I'll look into nebula route as well, but regex isn't quite what I'm looking for. For example, lets say that I want to explicitely route '/index.html' to the landing page as well, and maybe '/index' or '/home' or something. It would be better to define discrete alternatives rather than a regex.

Comment: @ViggyNash I'm not following how regex wouldn't help there. If I'm understanding correctly, you want three different patterns to route to the same page: `/index.html`, `/index`, or `/home`. That regex would look like this: [`/index(.html)?|home`](https://regex101.com/r/Y2I4Rr/1).

Comment: Yeah actually you're right. I was hoping there would be a more visually explicit option (regex isn't the easiest thing to read).